# Creating struts 2 forms dynamically on jsp using java script

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, struts2

What I require is a pretty standard feature. And I am sure its easy enough, but somehow I cant make it happen. Please help me out here.

This is the scenario-->

I have a struts form on a jsp, which takes in employee information. Now with every employee I want to associate some family members.

So for information of family members I want :

1.) A row of -- 1 select element and 3 text field elements -- in the end of the form.

2.) A 'add' button which appends such rows on demand for adding more family members.

I dont know how I can attach a screen shot to give you exact idea of what I want.

I have tried doing this, using javascript, but javascript adds standard HTML elements, because of which I am not able to access the value of those fields in my action class.(Please tell me if this is not the case, because then the only question that will remain is, why am I unable access those values)

Currently what I am trying:

JSP:

```
<s:form name="enterEmployeeInfo" id="enterEmployeeInfo" action="enterEmployeeInfo">

    ////OTHER FORM ELEMENTS//////////////

        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Relationship</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>Occupation</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="rel">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Father">Father</option>
                    <option value="Mother">Mother</option>
                    <option value="Spouse">Spouse</option>
                    <option value="Child">Child</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td> <input name="rName[]"/></td>
            <td> <input name="rAge"/>          </td>
            <td> <input name="rOccupation"/>   </td>
            <td colspan="4" align="right"><button type="button" onclick="tryFunc(this.parentNode);">Add</button></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <s:submit value="Add Employee" name="submit"/>
        <s:reset  value="Reset"       name="reset"/>
</s:form>
```

The JS:

```
function tryFunc(node){
    var root = node.parentNode.parentNode;
    var allRows = root.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var cRow = allRows[1].cloneNode(true);
    var cInp = cRow.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0;i<cInp.length;i++){
        cInp[i].setAttribute('name',cInp[0].getAttribute('name')+'_'+(allRows.length+1))
    }
    var cSel = cRow.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
    cSel.setAttribute('name',cSel.getAttribute('name')+'_'+(allRows.length+1));
    root.appendChild(cRow);
}
```

With this I am able to add a new row of specified elements, but unable to access the field values in the action class. I would like to point out that I am not able to access even the first row's elements in action class (probably because they are standard HTML).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: What you mean by Standard element??  even if you use struts2 tags they will be converted in to HTML when browser render them.tags are only for some convience

Comment: @Umesh I thought there is a difference in the way the struts elements communicate with the action class. Otherwise why am I not able to receive value in action class. I know in the source struts creates standard HTML Elements. It creates a table with two columns one for label and one for the element. Because of this I am unable to get 4 components side by side. Is there any other way to get these components side by side.

Comment: Well the tables is being created since you are using x_html theme which means those tables are being generated.if you don't want that table and TD use simple theme. [can-i-change-theme-on-a-per-page-basis](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/can-i-change-theme-on-a-per-page-basis.html). Regarding communication if you want to pull some data from the ValueStack only than it required.Show you action class as that needs same property name what you are sending from your form

Comment: Hey I am sorry, I just checked by adding a struts field and then too I got 'null' value. So I found out that the default getter and setter for my variable rName were named as getrName and setrName instead of getRName and setRName. This was causing the problem. I just discovered that netbeans is not capitalizing the first letter after 'get' and 'set' in the getter and setter respectively if the 2nd letter in the variable name is in Capitals.

Comment: Please provide answer to your question so that some one will able to get benefits if he/she has same issue

Comment: @Umesh One more thing. Is it possible to specify the name of an element like an array (like I have done in 'rName[]') and then access the values like this --> rName[0], rName[1]....... in the action class. I saw this in some post sometime back but now I cant find that post again. Because this will make my work easier.

Comment: You can declare `Array,List,Map` what ever you want,struts2 will take care of converting your incoming data to expected data-type all you need to do is when you want it as an Array or List, name should be same in your jsp page so Struts2 will know that you are sending the `Array/List`

Comment: Yes once I have figured it out completely and am sure it is a good way to do it, I will post the final answers so that others stuck in similar situation can get out of it.

Comment: @Umesh Ok. I am gonna try and do the array way of doing this and will post back. Thanks!!

Comment: @Umesh : I tried it. In textfield I put `name='rName[]'` and in action class I declared a variable like this `private String rName[];`. Then I defined getter and setter. But I am getting nullpointerException in this `for(int i=0;i<rName.length;i++){
            System.out.println(i + " : " + rName);
        }`.  Any ideas why? Do you need more information?

Comment: aha..You need array in your action only when you are sending array/list from your jsp like `<s:textfiled name="rName">` and such more fields with same name so they will be placed inside the array of your action

Comment: @Umesh : Yes now I got it. I removed the [] from the name of the element i.e I wrote `name='rName'` and now its working. Thanks!! Will post complete working code soon.

Comment: @Umesh : Just one more thing, the `select` element in the cloned row is not displaying the value selected in the original row.

Comment: @Umesh : Ok. Got it. Simple javascript. I have also posted the answer.

Comment: :) , i did not saw this.some weird SO issue, no notification in my mailbox

Comment: @Umesh No problem, You helped me solve the major trouble. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Umesh : Hi, I am still facing a small little problem in this. I have posted another question for that ( http://stackoverflow.com/q/8726237/870767 ). I was hoping you could help me with it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution to the problem, for those still stuck on it.

In the jsp:

```
<s:form name="enterEmployeeInfo" id="enterEmployeeInfo" action="enterEmployeeInfo">

    ////OTHER FORM ELEMENTS//////////////

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">Relationship</td>
                <td align="center">Name</td>
                <td align="center">Age</td>
                <td align="center">Occupation</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="rel">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Father">Father</option>
                        <option value="Mother">Mother</option>
                        <option value="Spouse">Spouse</option>
                        <option value="Child">Child</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td> <input name="rName"/></td>
                <td> <input name="rAge"/>          </td>
                <td> <input name="rOccupation"/>   </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" align="right"><button type="button" onclick="tryFunc(this.parentNode);">Add</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <s:submit value="Add Employee" name="submit"/>
        <s:reset  value="Reset"       name="reset"/>
</s:form>
```

The JS:

```
function tryFunc(node){
    var root = node.parentNode.parentNode;
    var allRows = root.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var cRow = allRows[1].cloneNode(true);
    root.appendChild(cRow);
}
```

Then in the action class, just define a variables like this:

```
    private String rel[];
    private String rName[];
    private String rAge[];
    private String rOccupation[];
```

Define their getters and setters, and you can access each element of each row in jsp like this :

```
    rel[0], rel[1], ........
    rName[0],rName[1], .......
    etc......
```

As for copying the Value of select element to cloned row, its simple javascript. Just do this:

```
    clonedSelect.selectedIndex = original.selectedIndex;
```

If you still have issues, comment. :)