# Cannot access the value of the selected item of a disabled drop down, in action class (struts 2)

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2, drop-down-menu, action

On a Jsp page I have some `select` elements which were disabled  after a value was selected (Disabled them in javascript). Now when the form is submitted, I can not access those selected values in the action class.

I know for sure that this is caused by the select elements being disabled because, when I tried the same without making them disabled, it worked fine.

Now I don't understand why is this so. I thought maybe I should enable them before the form is submitted, but it does not seem a good idea.

I faced this problem while implementing this : [Creating struts 2 forms dynamically on jsp using java script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8710858/870767) .
(You can find the code there. Although I don't think you will need the code, because it is clear where the problem is.)

Here I am able to access the values of text fields but I can not access the values of select elements.

I asked this question separately because I thought this is a different topic.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set them in hidden field through java script and pass it to action

Comment: Yeah that can be done (better than what I was thinking of doing), but I will have an array of select elements so I will have to make an array of hidden fields as well. So that will make more variables. If possible I would like a better way of doing it. More Ideas?

Comment: @kanishk If you want disabled form controls, and you must still send the values, that's your option. Another option would be to not require them to be re-sent--you got the values once, consider keeping them through the next request.

Comment: @Dave Ok then I guess I have to go with the hidden field way. Because I am not resending the selected option. The form is submitted only once, rest is happening in the javascript. I mean the cloning of the row and disabling of the select element is done in javascript.

Comment: @Jaychapani : Thanks Jay. I am finally going with what you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Disabled fields by W3 specifications will not get posted on the server side so this issue is not related to the Struts2 but in generic an HTML way to go

[Disabled controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1)

i am not sure why you want to use disabled control for your form.things can be done using readOnly attribute or use hidden fields

Comment: But select elements do not have a readOnly attribute. So had to use disabled. Nice link, Thanks!!

Comment: @kanishk: in that case follow what Dave has said

Comment: Yes, I am going to use hidden fields now.